# Error while acessing ui element from source file

Tags: c++, qt

I am creating basic application which include pushbutton on ui file.

When I compile application it gives error about pushbutton not found.

Below is code:

MainWindow.cpp:

```
#include <QPushButton>
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
pushButton->hide();
ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
 delete ui;
}
```

---

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
~MainWindow();

private:
Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

---

main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
QApplication a(argc, argv);
MainWindow w;
w.show();

return a.exec();
}
```

error got is:

> error: 'pushButton' was not declared in this scope

Comment: ui->setupUi(this); ui->pushButton->hide();

Answer (score 1):

I assume you used the QtCreator. The PushButton is a generated member of the UI class, so you need to dereference "ui" first. Also make sure you call setupUi before using any members of the ui object (otherwise the ui object will not be set up properly).

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->pushButton->hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have created this widget/mainwindow with Qtcreator and added the pushButton to the ui form, then your button is in `ui->pushButton` and you should use it after initializing the `ui` with `ui->setupUi(this)` call.

Comment: silly mistake. Thanks got it working with  "ui->pushButton->hide();"